# How can I create a ReSharper Live Template to suggest from a list of issue numbers?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper, live-templates

I have a ReSharper todo pattern called `BKWIP`, being my initials and this comment identifies a work in progress, i.e. an issue tracker item that I have started working on. I use this as follows:

```
// BKWIP HS-nn
```

where `HS-nn` is a ticket number from our issue tracker. I would now like to create a Live Template along the lines of:

```
// BKWIP $ISSUE_NO$ $COMMENT$
```

where `$ISSUE_NO$` invokes a Live Template macro to show a list of issue numbers. How do I create such a macro?

I am quite happy, for a start, to set up a text or xml file with issue numbers, i.e. I don't need to pull them directly from Jira or anything; just need to read them from some simple list store.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @breandan's suggestion of a comma delimited list of values, but this will give you a static list of items. If you wish, you can write a ReSharper extension that will give you a custom macro for the template, which can populate things just how you like - from an xml file, or by talking directly to an issue tracker (although I don't think it handles async lookups, so you might have to work off a cache that is updated in the background). Here are [the docs for writing Live Template Macros](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/devguide/Features/LiveTemplates/Macros.html).

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA there is a [Predefined Function](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-template-variables.html#predefined_functions) called `enum(...)` that will suggest a list of comma-delimited strings for completion at some parameter. There appears to be a similar feature in ReSharper called [Comma-delimited list of values](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Reference__Choose_Macro.html) to display a static list of values from a [template parameter](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Templates__Creating_and_Editing_Templates__Declaring_Variables.html). I would give that one a try.